# How to execute two functions one by one in python and get the desired output

Tags: python, python-2.7

here is my code

```
students=["X" ,"Y" ,"Z" ]
age=[20,22,26]

def names():
    global students
    for students in students: 
        print "your name is"+" "+students+" "+"your age is" 
names()

def ages():
    global age
    for age in age: 
        print age 

ages()
```

**wanted output**

```
your name is X your age is 20  
your name is Y your age is 22 
your name is Z your age is 26
```

**actual output**

```
your name is X your age is  
your name is Y your age is  
your name is Z your age is  
20 
22 
26
```

How can I execute the functions one by one and get the wanted output.

Comment: You don't need function for this. Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
students = ["X" ,"Y" ,"Z" ]
ages = [20,22,26]

for name, age in zip(students, ages):
    print 'your name is', name ,'your age is', age
```

Comment: ahead for 5 secs, nice job :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> students=["X" ,"Y" ,"Z" ]
>>> age=[20,22,26]
>>> d = dict(zip(students, age))
>>> for k, v in d.items():
        print 'your name is', k ,'your age is', v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
students=["X" ,"Y" ,"Z" ]
age=[20,22,26]

for i, name in enumerate(students):
    print "your name is", name, "and your age is", age[i]
```

**EDIT**

have to admit that using `zip` as another answer says is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is iterate through students and keep index i with enumeration.

```
for i, student in enumerate (students):
    print "Your name is " + student +", "+ age[i]
```